# Optimizing MySQL query for the Tatoeba project

Tags: mysql, optimization

I've downloaded the [Tatoeba project databases](http://tatoeba.org/eng/download_tatoeba_example_sentences) and I'm trying to query them but queries with a subquery are taking way too long.

```
-- 800.000 rows approx.
CREATE TABLE `sentences` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `language` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=912551 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


-- 1.5 million rows approx.
CREATE TABLE `links` (
  `sentenceId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `translatedId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sentenceId`,`translatedId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Basically the links table joins two sentences in the `sentences` table together (the original sentence and one  translation). A sentence can have zero or more translations. So I have an id of a sentence I want to work with and want to grab ALL the translations available.

**This query gets me what I want but takes almost 18 seconds to complete.**

```
SELECT * FROM `sentences` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `translatedId` FROM `links` WHERE `sentenceId` = 157967);
```

Running both queries by themselves just takes an instant.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `sentences`.* FROM 
  `sentences` JOIN 
  `links` ON `id` = `translatedId` 
WHERE `sentenceId` = 157967;
```

Some versions of MySQL are known not to use indexes in sub-queries.

Comment: Hey thanks, this worked! Would you mind pointing out what I was doing wrong?

Comment: @julian: You were doing nothing wrong. Your query is 100% correct. Problem is that MySQL currently (it will hopefully be fixed in future versions) doesn't handle well some queries with `IN`. So, one has to check other ways to write the same query, using either `JOIN` or the `EXISTS` version by Cybernate and see which is faster with one's data.

Comment: And a question: Do you have indexes in the tables and if yes, what indexes?

Comment: Indexes are well seen in the original question. They are all right.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you for the explanation. @ypercube While my original post had a compound index, I tried the same query with every possible index combination to same results (some lasting even longer than 20 seconds!)

Answer (score 1):

Try this(using an EXISTS clause):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `sentences` a
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `links` b WHERE `sentenceId` = 157967 AND b.`translatedId`=a.`id`);
```

If the translatedId is unique in the `links` you can go for a inner join as given below

```
SELECT a.* 
    FROM `sentences` a INNER JOIN `links` b
      ON b.`translatedId`=a.`id`
```